# Avoid unnecessary for loops in recursive function in C#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, nested-loops, object-comparison

I have CSV template file with different data files with filenames in below format that reads and store in `CSVTemplate` model

**Note:** The  data is CSV file for each file types with names will be ordered.

```
id,FileType,FileName
1,Excel Files, Excel File 1
2,Excel Files, Excel File 2
3,Excel Files, Excel File 2.1
4,Document Files, Document File 1,
5,Document Files, Document File 2
6,Document Files, Document File 3
7,Document Files, Document File 3.1
8,Document Files, Document File 3.2
```

**Model:**

```
    public class CSVTemplate
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        
        public string FileType{ get; set; }

        public string FileName{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Code for reading CS Records:** I am using  [CSVHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) NuGet package

```
       public List<CSVTemplate> Fetch_TemplateData()
        {
            List<CSVTemplate> csvTemplateData = new List<CSVTemplate>();

            try
            {
                   string csvFilePath = @"File1.csv";


                //CSVHelper Configuration Settings
                var csvconfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                {
                    NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    DetectDelimiterValues = new string[] { "," },
                };

                //Reading CSV File 
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
                {
                    //Fetching CSV Records
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvconfig))
                    {
                        csvTemplateData = csv.GetRecords<CSVTemplate>().ToList();
                    }
                };

                return csvTemplateData;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I have below JSON response from WebAPI contains file names in `title` for all types of files which is nested and inner nested.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "Field": [
    {
      "title": "Excel Files",
      "Field": [
        {
          "title": "Excel File 1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Excel File 2",
          "Field": [
            {
              "title": "Excel File 2.1"
            },
            {
              "title": "Excel File 2.2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "Excel File 3",
          "Field": [
            {
              "title": "Excel File 3.1",
              "Field": [
                {
                  "title": "Excel File 3.1.1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Document Files",
      "Field": [
        {
          "title": "Document File 1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Document File 2",
          "Field": [
            {
              "title": "Document File 2.1"
            },
            {
              "title": "Document File 2.2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "Document File 3",
          "Field": [
            {
              "title": "Document File 3.1",
              "Field": [
                {
                  "title": "Document File 3.1.1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

CSV file contains mandatory file names of all file types. webapi response (json) contains mandatory and non mandatory file names. I need to compare CSV with webapi data and check if mandatory filenames are missed.

**Model:**

```
    public class Field
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
    }
```

**Updated Code:**

```
  
    public bool Validate_TemplateData(List<CSVTemplate> csvData)
        {
            bool isTemplateValidate = false;
            try
            {
                string jsonFile = @".\json1.json";
                string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
                Root jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
                if (jsondata != null)
                {
                    bool isMatched = false;
                    foreach (var csvRowData in csvData)
                    {
                        var csvTitle = csvRowData.FileName;
                        foreach (var field in jsondata)
                        {
                            isMatched  = CheckFieldTitle(field, 0, csvTitle);
                            if (isMatched)
                            {
                               break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!isMatched)
                        {
                             Console.WriteLine($"Title : {csvTitle} Not matched.");
                             break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return isTemplateValidate;

        }
```

**Recursive Function :** to read all nested field names/titles from JSON.

```
   private static bool CheckFieldTitle(Field field, int level, string csvTitle)
        {
            bool isTileMatched = false;
            try
            {
                var fieldTitle = field.Title;

                if (csvTitle.Trim().ToUpper().Equals(fieldTitle.Trim().ToUpper()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {csvTitle} Matched");
                    isTileMatched = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //check in Nested Fields
                    foreach (var subFields in field.Field)
                    {
                        isTileMatched = PrintSection(subSections, sectionLevel + 1, csvTitle);
                        if (isTileMatched)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                isTileMatched = false;
                throw;
            }
            return isTileMatched;
        }
```

**Output:**

I want output which are missed in JSON data but available in  CSV file.

`Document File 3.2`

**Conditions:**

- If comparison failed at any level of loop with any file type, the rest of comparison should not proceed.
  `Example: Comparison failed at Excel File 2, so print Excel File 2 and stop comparison for all rest of files and file types.`
- Comparison logic should be for each CSV row data with each web API response field title(json). It should not be like fetching entire JSON FileNames(Titles) as 1 list, and CSV Data(FileNames) as another list and do compare both list for differences.
- Comparison should be Order of JSON data. (In this example, first compare all excel files and then Document Files)

**Problem:**

- The code is partially working but numerous of loops happening in recursive function which I would like to avoid.

**Best Options:**

- To use any  third party Nuget Packages (Object Comparison) for this kind of problem to optimize the code which I am unable to find.
- Unable to do with LINQ query to optimize for each calls in solution.

Comment: Maybe this is a naming thing, but it's weird to me that your `FetchFieldTitle` doesn't seem to mutate any data structures (well, it logs, but that's uninteresting to me -- perhaps that's my bad) and only returns a bool, yet when you call it recursively, you ignore the return value.  So this is a glorified logging function at the moment.  It doesn't "fetch" anything.  Seems like this is a case of something being named poorly.  "LogMatchingFieldTitles" is what it actually does, right?  Or maybe you need to use the return value and `break` out of the loop if the result is going to be true?

Comment: Perhaps the recursive function should also do:  `isTileMatched = FetchFieldTitle(subFields, level + 1, csvTitle);` then immediately check `if (isTileMatched) return true;` to stop further recursion once you know the result will be true.  (Exception behaviour notwithstanding - which changes the behaviour slightly.)

Comment: @Wyck ```FetchFieldTitle``` return type is set to bool for my reference to know its matched or not. But i am not sure what return type/what kind of model will set for this function. May be i need to enhance my code a bit more.

Comment: In your `Validate_TemplateData` template, there is a `break` inside the body of the loop is not conditional.  The second and subsequent iterations of your loop are therefore unreachable.  That seems like a bug.

Comment: @Wyck I had found this bug and fixed also, updated my code. I need help in optimization the code as the recursive for each loop is running multiple times unnecessarily for all file types. Ex: if am checking for Document file, recursive function is running from Excel file and checking through. Probably I might need to break my code in to FileTypes and check data.

Comment: `public List<Field> Field` appears to be invalid C#?

Comment: Why does point 2 matter? You are getting the entire CSV and the entire list at once, then you can compare them in order.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you group the files by `FileType` from the JSON and then find the first missing CSV file.

First, convert the JSON into a `Dictionary` by FileType and gather all the titles into a `HashSet<string>`:

```
var jData = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
var jd = jData.SelectToken("Field")
              .ToDictionary(f => f["title"],
                            f => f["Field"].SelectTokens("..title")
                                           .Select(jt => jt.ToString())
                                           .ToHashSet());
```

Then, convert the CSV file into a list of `CSVTemplate`. I just did some simple code (not for production use):

```
var csvTemplateData = csvSrc.Split('\n').Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split(','))
                            .Select(va => new CSVTemplate {
                                id = va[0].ToInt(),
                                FileType = va[1],
                                FileName = va[2].Trim()
                            })
                            .ToList();
```

(`ToInt()` is the obvious extension method.)

Finally, you can find the first missing filename by checking each `CSVTemplate` in order to see if it is present:

```
var firstMissing = csvTemplateData.FirstOrDefault(t => !jd[t.FileType]
                                  .Contains(t.FileName))
                                  ?.FileName;
```

`firstMissing` will be `null` if no missing CSV FileName is found, otherwise it will contain the FileName. If you prefer, you can leave off the `?.FileName` to get the first missing `CSVTemplate`.